# Numerate record from some value

Tags: sql-server

I need to select a field from the table and numerate it from some value.  Something like this:

```
DECLARE @n AS INT
SET @n = 1111
SELECT F, @n = @n + 1 FROM MYTABLE
```

Is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't combine variable assignments with row selects. You might use [ROW_NUMBER](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/us-en/library/ms186734.aspx) instead

```
Declare @n int= 1111
Select ID, @n + ROW_NUMBER() Over (Order by ID)
from aTable
```